# VM Bridged network adapter not receiving IP address from DHCP Windows 8 Host and XP VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, windows-8.1

I have virtualised an ancient XP machine that was on physical hardware that was dying and am running the VM from inside a windows 8 64-bit host on the same network.

The VM is required to be on the same network as host as it is the only thing configured to talk to a piece of equipment connected on the network.

However when I set the adapter to Bridge mode in the VM the XP Vm doesnt recieve an IP address and cant communicate on the network. It works in NAT mode, however then the VM cant be on the same network as host and see the hardware that it needs to talk to.

Any one think of a reason why Bridge mode isn't working? and what I could do to fix it.

Summary

```
Windows 8 64bit, VM Player 10 Host
XP 32bit VM.
Bridged adaptor not working on host network.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well the answer was not so simple. 
Basically the switch that the host computer is connected to is a Cisco switch with port security enabled. So it wasn't allowing the second MAC address from my VM access to the network.  I contacted the networking guys and they removed port security for the particular port (or upped the limit on the number of devices allowed on the port) and all is good now.